# How to set an alarm for every 1 minute, for same say only in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I made one application with Android native. I'm using AlarmManager for achieving every 1-minute track data.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),100000,pendingIntent);
```

But I want that it must stop on specific time like today 12 P.M. or whatever time I want.

How can I achieve it by making another AlarmManager Service, or is there any other option for this?

Comment: use service that cancel ongoing alarm . For that you have to set fixed id of pending intent. and from service cancel that pending intent

Comment: How we set fixed id to pending intent. and if i want to set it from other AlarmManger Service is it possible?

Comment: this line, PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), "ID_OF_PENDING", intent, 0); . now from anywhere write above line except last line and put alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent); with same ID

Comment: yes, it may work. by the way thanks for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check in service launched by Alarm that current time early than your specific time

```
if (isTimeExpired) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);    
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```